# $a_1 k^{b_1} + a_2 k^{b_2} + ... + a_n k^{b_n} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ such that $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n = 0$. If there exists a real $k > 0$ different from $1$ and distinct real numbers $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ such that 
$$a_1 k^{b_1} + a_2 k^{b_2} + ... + a_n k^{b_n} = 0,$$

then $a_1 = a_2 = ... = a_n = 0$.

If $n = 2$, then the equation is equivalent to $a_1k^{b_1} = a_1 k^{b_2}$. Since $b_1 \neq b_2$, this is only possible if $a_1 = 0$, so $a_1 = a_2 = 0$.

For $n = 3$ we have 
$$a_1 k^{b_1 - b_3} + a_2 k^{b_2 - b_3} = a_1 + a_2. \text{  } (*)$$

Clearly $b_1 - b_3 \neq 0$, $b_2 - b_3 \neq 0$, so if $a_1, a_2$ are both different from $0$, then the function
$$f(x) = a_1x^{c_1} + a_2x^{c_2}$$

is non-constant. I believe that it is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing for $x>0$, depending on $c_1,c_2$; Then it would be injetive, and since $f(1) = a_1+a_2$, this would mean that the only solution to $(*)$ is $k = 1$, which contradicts the hypothesis,so $a_1 = a_2 = 0$.

I don't know how to proceed. How would one prove this in the general case?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to show that the claim is wrong already for $n=3$. To see this it suffices to put $k=2$,
$a_1=a_2=1$, $a_3=-2$, $b_1=1$, $b_2=2$, $b_3=\log_2 3$.